# How to find Next Prime Number in Java presented by GUI Label

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to find the next (larger) prime number which will displayed on the label in GUI
But the code below is not okay.
Maybe the problem is d++, however I cannot think of other way to let the loop continue.
Can anyone help?
Thanks so much.

```
public class PrimeNumber extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JLabel label = new JLabel("2");
    private JButton button = new JButton("Next Prime");

    public PrimeNumber() {
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        this.setLayout(layout);
        label = new JLabel("2");
        button = new JButton("Next Prime");
        this.add(label);
        this.add(button);

        button.addActionListener(this);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();

    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int d = 2;
        
        do {
            String t = String.valueOf(d);
            label.setText(t);
            d++;

        }
        while (d % 2 != 0);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TestPrimeNumber {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PrimeNumber frame = new PrimeNumber();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Are you asking how to find the next prime number?  Or is there something else wrong?

Comment: Because I want to keep showing the next Prime number when I press the button , but it stopped since I get 3.

Comment: Well, you're always starting your search of the next prime back at 2; you need to start with whatever number is already being shown in the label.

Comment: I want to try  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int d >= 2;  But it show error

Comment: Try `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { int d = Integer.parseInt(label.getText())` instead.